# Web Share API - Share files from server

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-devtools, share

I want to create a website to share files to a WhatsApp chat. 
This should be possible in chrome by using the Web Share API https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/05/web-share-files The demo in the description works but only with files uploaded with the form. In my case, the files are already on the server. 
Has anyone done this before and can help me with the code? 
Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: The Web Share API is a client-side API but judging by the question you need to find a server-side solution.

Comment: In this example https://web.dev/web-share/ it looks like it should work.

Comment: Why? AFAICT the word "web" means it's a feature available only in a web browser but do you run your server app via a browser on your server?

Comment: In my opinion and definition a web application or "web app" is a software program that runs on a web server that must be accessed through a web browser.

Comment: Well, the fact is that this API can't use remote files. If you want to use it in your client-side app (in the browser) then you'll have to download the files and probably use FormData and/or Blob to supply the files. My initial idea though is to find a server-side solution which will be something entirely different from this API.

Comment: thanks for your clarification. I think I misunderstood the function of the API. But is there server-side solution?